# OpenGL ES texture working on Emulator but not on Device

Tags: android, opengl-es, texture-mapping

I tried everything, but I can't make the OpenGL ES texture to work in my device, even when it works on emulator.

**Source code:**

**Texture class:**

```
public class XAndroidTexture 
{
    private int[] textures = new int[1];
    public int width, height;
    Bitmap bmp;

    public XAndroidTexture(GL10 gl, Bitmap bitmap) 
    {
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        this.bmp = bitmap;
        width = bmp.getWidth();
        height = bmp.getHeight();
        gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
        // ...and bind it to our array
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

        // create nearest filtered texture
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);

        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

         gl.glTexEnvf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL10.GL_MODULATE);
        // Use Android GLUtils to specify a two-dimensional texture image from our bitmap 
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
         //GLUtils.texSubImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, bmp);

        // Clean up
        bitmap.recycle();

    }

    public void bind(GL10 gl)
    {
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
    }

    public static XAndroidTexture createTextureFromBitmap(GL10 gl, Bitmap bmp) 
    {
        return new XAndroidTexture(gl, bmp);
    }
}
```

**Texture loading function:**

```java
public XAndroidTexture Textureload(String path)
    {
        InputStream is;
        Bitmap bmp = null;
        try 
            {
                is = this.getAssets().open(path);

                BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                opts.inDither = true;
                Bitmap tBmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, opts);
                bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(tBmp.getWidth(), tBmp.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
                canvas.drawBitmap(tBmp, 0, 0, null);
                canvas.save();
                tBmp.recycle();
                tBmp = null;
            } 
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(bmp == null)
                return null;
            else
                return new XAndroidTexture(gl, bmp);
    }
```

It is working on Emulator perfectly fine, but not on device.
Can anyone post here texture class that work on device?

Answer (score 0):

Check the link below.. i too got same problem. i got solution from the link.

[Trying to draw textured triangles on device fails, but the emulator works. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113638/trying-to-draw-textured-triangles-on-device-fails-but-the-emulator-works-why)